# Add new row if there's no duplicate on enter key

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table where I get to insert a data via bardcode scanner. The goal is to ignore a data if it already exists on the table, else, continue to add row.

My JS Function:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]', function(e){
    var retrieve_checker = true;
    get_last_id();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var seen = {};
        $('#receiving-box-table input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]').each(function() {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            alert(txt);
            if (seen[txt]){
                $(this).val('');

                retrieve_checker = false;
                return false;
            } else{
                seen[txt] = true;
                retrieve_checker = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        if(retrieve_checker == true){
            $('#receiving-box-table tbody').append(new_row);
            $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.track_no').focus();
            var new_val = parseInt($('#retrieve_box_qty').val()) + 1;
            $('#retrieve_box_qty').val(new_val);
            $('#'+another_lel).val(new_val);
        }
    }
});
```

My issue with this:

1. Nothing happens. Only the first enter key press works

But if I change my code a bit to this:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#receiving-box-table tr:last-child td:first-child input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]', function(e){
    var retrieve_checker = true;
    get_last_id();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var seen = {};
        $('#receiving-box-table input[name^="retrieve_courier_tracking_no[]"]').each(function() {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            if (seen[txt]){
                $(this).val('');

                retrieve_checker = false;
                return false;
            } else{
                seen[txt] = true;
                retrieve_checker = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        //if(retrieve_checker == true){
            $('#receiving-box-table tbody').append(new_row);
            $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input.track_no').focus();
            var new_val = parseInt($('#retrieve_box_qty').val()) + 1;
            $('#retrieve_box_qty').val(new_val);
            $('#'+another_lel).val(new_val);
        //}
    }
});
```

My issue with this:

1. It adds rows on enter key press but duplicate data are still added.
2. **It says that it's duplicate even if the data I just entered is not.**

I think there's something wrong with my each function but I'm not sure what.

**UPDATE INFO**

I have the same exact function that does it and WORKS. But I can't use it since the button that triggers my new function is not initially loaded, thus my usage of `$(document).on...`

I've been stuck for hours so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle here

Comment: @user8175473 https://jsfiddle.net/190htj5o/